# Current frame playing in an animation

Tags: javascript, animation, frame, cocoscreator

I am working on a roulette game with Cocos Creator.

The wheel and the spinning ball has sprite animation.

I want to sync the wheel rotation and ball spinning. 
I need to know the current frame playing.

Can anyone suggest a method to do this?